# Timestamp comparison in hive

Tags: sql, date, hive, timestamp, hiveql

I need to compare date with format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00 and yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

I tried with.

```
start_date > date_format('2021-12-15 00:00:00');
```

I got the results however the query returns additional line.

Any suggestions please

Comment: date_format requires second argument - format pattern

Comment: Why don't you compare the same formats?

Answer (score 1):

Convert date predicate to the same format, like this:

date_format('2021-12-15 00:00:00', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+00:00")

And take care about correct format. `mm` - means minutes, `MM`-means month, `hh` - is a 12 - base hours, not 24. HH- means 24 base hours. `hh` without am/pm makes no sense. Double check format in your question, it has multiple issues.

Comment: It works without T ;)